# How to set frame for CATransition in iOS

Tags: ios

Iam new to ios development.I have one doubt related to CATransition.I placed one imageview with one image from top to middle of the screen(0,0,320,250).Iam using animation to animate the image from bottom to top in viewdidload method.But the image is animating from bottom of self.view, But i need to animate the image from height 250 not from 568.

The code what iam using is below:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;

[topImage.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

[image]

in the image where we have cyan color iam placing image there.i need to animate the image from starting of black color.

If any konw the answer please let me know.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score -1):

@09121989 Write the Below Code

```
CABasicAnimation *moveUP;
moveUP            = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
  [moveUP setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-imag.frame.size.height/2)]];
    moveUP.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:imag.frame.size.height/2.0];
moveUP.duration   = 2.0;
moveUP.removedOnCompletion = NO;
moveUP.fillMode   = kCAFillModeForwards;
moveUP.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
return moveUP;
```

Comment: the code which i mentioned above is calling on viewdidload